# Best practice for Cocoa category naming conventions

Tags: cocoa, categories

I am tidying up my ancient Cocoa code to use modern naming conventions.  There has been lots of discussion on best practices, but I'm unsure of one thing.

I'm thinking about adding a prefix to category method names, to ensure uniqueness.  It seem generally agreed that this is a good idea, though most people probably don't bother.

My question is: what about a `NSDictionary` category method like `-copyDeep` that does a deep copy?  The method used to be named `-deepCopy`, but I reversed the words as the analyzer looks for a prefix of "copy".  Therefore I presumably couldn't add a prefix.  And having the "prefix" in the middle or end of the method name seems messy and inconsistent.

I'd also be interested in thoughts on the style of prefix -- I currently use `DS` (for Dejal Systems) for class prefixes.  But I know that Apple now wants to reserve all two-character prefixes for themselves, so am thinking about using `Dejal`, e.g. my class `DSManagedObject` would be renamed as `DejalManagedObject`.  And getting back to categories, their methods would be renamed to add a `dejal` prefix, e.g. from `-substringFromString:` to `-dejalSubstringFromString:`.  But `-dejalCopyDeep` would confuse the analyzer, so maybe I'd have to be inconsistent for such methods, and use `-copyDeepDejal` or `-copyDeep_dejal`?

I will be re-releasing my categories and various classes as open source once I've cleaned them up, so following the latest conventions will be beneficial.

Comment: good question! i'm curious about how you say apple wants to reserve two-char prefixes - i'm just wondering where you got that info from? when you create new projects it does suggest a 3 char prefix, but has there been an official statement on it?

Comment: I can't find an official document that states that, but I believe it was mentioned in a [WWDC10 session on future-proofing](https://deimos.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/BrowsePrivately/adc.apple.com.4092349126.04109539109.4144345635?i=2082492890).

Comment: Revisiting this old question, I found documentation on the 3-char prefix recommendation, on the [Programming with Objective-C: Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html) page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I emailed the Apple Application Frameworks Evangelist about this, and got a reply that recommended **not** prefixing category method names.  Which conflicts with the advice in the aforelinked WWDC10 session, but I assume reflects Apple's current thinking.

He recommended just looking at the beta seed API diffs to spot conflicts, which is what I've always been doing.

Comment: You absolutely should prefix your category methods.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kevin Ballard, you should prefix your category method names, particularly if you are going to distribute them to others. But you do have a valid concern the analyzer will be confused by `DScopy`. The ARC compiler will similarly be confused if the definition/implementation of `DScopy` is done without ARC and is used by another class using ARC (or vice versa).

My preferred solution is to use "ownership transfer annotations", such as:

```
NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED 
NS_RETURNS_RETAINED
```

They would be used to override the compilers default behavior of reading method names and acting on them. You might declare `DScopy` like so: (**This declaration must be in a header file that is imported by all the classes that use this method** mentioned due to link)

```
-(DSManagedObject *)DScopy; NS_RETURNS_RETAINED;
```

Source for `NS_RETURNS...` WWDC 2011 Session 322 - Objective-C Advancements in Depth. The meat of this issue begins at about time 9:10.

A note about "But I know that Apple now wants to reserve all two-character prefixes for themselves". As a personal preference I like to use the `_` character to separate the prefix from the name, it works well for me. You might try something like:

```
-(DSManagedObject *)ds_copy; NS_RETURNS_RETAINED;
```

This would give you three characters, and arguably make the method name more readable.

**Edit** In response to link posted in comment.

However as Justin's answer to your original question says that can be broken.

With regards to attributes; I did not suggest using `__attribute__((objc_method_family(copy)))` I suggested using `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED`, which translates to :`__attribute__((ns_returns_retained))`. While the first example there won't even compile (as he says) using `- (NSString *)string __attribute__((objc_method_family(copy)));` it compiles with `- (NSString *)string; NS_RETURNS_RETAINED;` just fine.

Obviously also if the `NS_RETURNS_..` are "hidden" from the compiler in separate the `.m`s or indirected in some other way and the compiler can't see the directives then it won't work. Because of this I would suggest putting the declaration for any methods that may cause the analyzer/compiler confusion in your main `.h` file (the one that imports all the others) to limit the chances that there will be an issue.

Comment: You might like to [read the comprehensive answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770872/deep-copy-of-dictionaries-gives-analyze-error-in-xcode-4-2) I got from @Justin when originally asking about my `deepCopy` method, which I renamed to `copyDeep` to fit with the naming conventions.  But I am leaning towards using method prefixes in my categories, with `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` for the few methods that need it.

Comment: @Dejal Thanks for the link. I actually really did enjoy it. I updated my answer to be a little less dogmatic and respond in general.