# With ARC, do CGMutablePathRefs need to be released?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, automatic-ref-counting

I've been searching around but haven't found a clear answer if Core Graphic primitives (CGMutablePathRef, CGPath, gradients, etc.) need to be released when using ARC (+ iOS6).

I've seen this ([silence a compiler warning about releasing a CGMutablePathRef object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816503/silence-a-compiler-warning-about-releasing-a-cgmutablepathref-object)) and a few other questions but they are either out of date or not entirely clear (to me at least).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Roughly said, only `NSObject` instances are handled through ARC. ARC is a compiler mechanism that adds `release`/`retain` for you when needed. So, it only applies in cases where you could use `release`/`retain` in the non-ARC case.

This does not include either memory allocated through `malloc`, nor low-level frameworks (core graphics, core audio, etc.). Specifically, objects allocated through low-level frameworks need to be released by using specific methods (e.g., `CGImageRelease`, etc.).

EDIT:

A very specific case of Core Foundation data types are *toll-free bridged* types. In pre-ARC world you could safely specify a CF data type where its correspondent Objective-C class was expected (e.g., CFString in place of NSString). ARC forbids this since ownership semantics would not be clear. Thus, a set of ARC directives are available to specify that ownership information (see [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html) for more info), but this is not the case of `CGPath`, which is not toll-free bridged (since it is not stated in [CGPath Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html)).

By the way, a great resource for all ARC-doubts is [this rich post of Mike Ash's](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html).

Comment: +1 Note that toll-free bridged CF classes can be brought under ARC's control using bridged casts.

Comment: @Andrew Madsen: thanks. I added the relevant info to my answer for completeness, although it does no apply to OP's case.